Vowpal Wabbit: contextual bandit with action dependent features not finding optimal solution
The question: why is our VPW MAB model not finding the (quite simple) optimal solution, and how can we fix the model call so that it does find the optimal solution?
We are trying to use VPW to fit a contextual MAB, with action dependent features, and quadratic feature interactions. However, we think we may be incorrectly entering the arguments, or in some way incorrectly specifying the model we want to fit. We think this because even in a toy example the model does not find the optimal solution.
model = pyvw.Workspace("--cb_explore_adf --quadratic CA --loss_function squared --learning_rate 0.5 --epsilon 0.2 --invert_hash estimate_weights.txt")

Here is the toy example.

1 feature: gender
2 actions: sports and news

The rewards are:
Male

sports :  5000

news: -5000


Female

sports: 5000
news: 10000

Thus, the MAB should choose (via propensity score) sports for males, news for females and achieve an expected reward of 7500. Instead, it achieves only an expected reward of approximately 5000, for both genders.
Here is code to walk through our reproducible example.
import random
from vowpalwabbit import pyvw

# Create VW instance for CMAB with shared context and action-dependent features
model = pyvw.Workspace("--cb_explore_adf --quadratic CA --loss_function squared --learning_rate 0.5 --epsilon 0.2 --invert_hash estimate_weights.txt")

def generate_train_data(num_samples):
    train_data = []
    for _ in range(num_samples):

        # Randomly set gender and action with probability 0.5
        gender_F = random.choice([0, 1])
        action_sports_chosen = random.choice([True, False])
        
        ### Compute the reward for both actions ##

        # Noise for rewards
        noise1 = 100*random.random() - 50
        noise2 = 100*random.random() - 50

        # Rewards for both actions, contingent on gender
        if gender_F:
            # female
            reward_sports = 5000 + noise1
            reward_news = 10000 + noise2
        else: 
            # male
            reward_sports = 5000 + noise1
            reward_news = -5000 + noise2

        # Note: Model SHOULD choose:
        ## news if gender_F == 1
        ## sports if gender_F == 0

        if action_sports_chosen:
            entry = f"shared |Customer gender_F:{gender_F}\n0:{-reward_sports}:0.5 |Action name=sports\n|Action name=news"
        else:
            entry = f"shared |Customer gender_F:{gender_F}\n|Action name=sports\n0:{-reward_news}:0.5 |Action name=news"

        train_data.append(entry)
    
    return train_data

# Example usage
num_samples = 100_000
train_data = generate_train_data(num_samples)

# Print the first few samples to verify
for line in train_data[:3]:
    print(line)
    print()

# Train the model
for epoch in range(10): 
    for example in train_data:
        model.learn(example)

print(f"cost: {model.get_sum_loss()/(num_samples*10):.2f}")

# Fail: ~-5000 --> not distinguishing between actions based on Gender   
# Success: ~-7500 --> making best decision per gender

Note: we tried different learning rates, to no effect.
